# mongoose query array, with id array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to query entries in an array, the document looks like this:

```
{
   "_id":"5d7b4ef6f691b71b5097e9cb",
   "name":"1568362230828",
   "commands":[
      {
         "_id":"5d7b4ef6f691b71b5097e9d1",
         "name":"Command - 0"
      },
      {
         "_id":"5d7b4ef6f691b71b5097e9d0",
         "name":"Command - 1"
      },
      {
         "_id":"5d7b4ef6f691b71b5097e9cf",
         "name":"Command - 2"
      },
      {
         "_id":"5d7b4ef6f691b71b5097e9ce",
         "name":"Command - 3"
      },
      {
         "_id":"5d7b4ef6f691b71b5097e9cd",
         "name":"Command - 4"
      },
      {
         "_id":"5d7b4ef6f691b71b5097e9cc",
         "name":"Command - 5"
      }
   ],
   "__v":0
}
```

now i want to get all commands by there id:

```js
model.find({
commands: {
_id: ["5d7b4ef6f691b71b5097e9cf", "5d7b4ef6f691b71b5097e9cf"] }})
```

Pseudo query, this does not work!

How must my query looks like ?!

```js
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    commands: [{
        name: String
    }]
});

const model = mongoose.model('Endpoints', schema);
```

Comment: `model.find({"commands._id": {$in:["5d7b4ef6f691b71b5097e9cf", "5d7b4ef6f691b71b5097e9cf"] }})` will return you all models that have at least one command with given id.

Comment: i need only the commands (as array) with the given ids

Comment: Then you need to use aggregation, extract commands on application level, or query commands collection. How your "model" and "command" schemas are defined in mongoose?

Comment: added the schema, i hoped i can only filter for the given/needed commands

Comment: Cool, so commands are embedded. Use [aggregation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to un-filter comments in comments only document then use this query

```
Endpoints.find({
   commands: {
     $elemMatch: {
       _id: { $in: ["5d7b4ef6f691b71b5097e9cf", "5d7b4ef6f691b71b5097e9cf"] }
     }
   }
});
```

If you want to filter comments in comments

```
Endpoints.aggregate([
   {
      $project: {
         items: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$commands",
               as: "item",
               cond: { 
                   $in: [ 
                      "$$item._id",
                      ["5d7b4ef6f691b71b5097e9cf", "5d7b4ef6f691b71b5097e9cf"]
                   ]
              }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

or without aggregation

```
Endpoints.find(
     { commands: 
       {$elemMatch: {"_id": { $in: ["5d7b4ef6f691b71b5097e9d1"]}}}
     }, 
     { 'commands.$': 1 }
 )
```